Fluentd plugin how to parse a value with a dynamic key?
Here is the input
message= [
      {
          "SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0"=>"338 days, 20:31:17.37", 
          "SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0"=>"IF-MIB::linkDown",  
          "IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.16896000"=>"1", 
          "IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.16896000"=>"2", 
          "IF-MIB::ifDescr.16896000"=>"fc1/30", 
          "host"=>"192.168.21.15"}
    ]

I want the output is
output= [
      {
          "interface"=>"fc1/30", 
          "host"=>"192.168.21.15"}
    ]

The problem is the key for fc1/30 is dynamic because the number 16896000 will change. I want to use this regular expression to filter the key: ^IF-MIB::ifDescr(?:.\d+)?$. But I don't know if any plugin support that.
I tried grep plugin, but seems this regexp doesn't support dynamic key?
  @type grep
  <regexp>
    key message
    pattern ???
  </regexp>

I tried parser, but it somehow doesn't working. seems it can only parse string but the input is json? Maybe I can convert the json input to string but I don't know how to do that.
  @type parser
  key_name message
  emit_invalid_record_to_error false
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /IF-MIB::ifDescr.*=>(?<interface>.*)/
  </parse>

Any one has ideas?
